# Assessing Xml node values with xmlnamespace

Tags: c#, xml, xmlreader, xelement

I am trying to access "shl:Value" node using c# but getting null or run time error. I like avoid using big loops.

Code:

```
XmlDocument objXmlDoc1 = new XmlDocument();
objXmlDoc1.Load("C:\\inetpub\\Jobtrain\\test.xml");

XmlReader reader = XmlReader.Create(new StringReader(objXmlDoc1.InnerXml));
XElement root = XElement.Load("C:\\inetpub\\Jobtrain\\test.xml");
XmlNameTable nameTable = reader.NameTable;
XmlNamespaceManager namespaceManager = new XmlNamespaceManager(nameTable);
namespaceManager.AddNamespace("shl", "http://www.shl.com");

sScore_Raw = root.XPathSelectElement(".//shl:Scales/shl:Scale[@Tag='SHL_VAT_GENERAL_ABILITY_SCREEN_SCORE']/shl:Values/shl:Value[@Tag='RAW SCORE']", namespaceManager).Value;
```

Error On following lines

```
sJTCandidateID = root.XPathSelectElement(".//ClientOrderId/IdValue[@name='ThirdPartyCandidateId']", namespaceManager).Value;
sTestStatus = root.XPathSelectElement(".//AssessmentStatus/Status", namespaceManager).Value;
```

XML:

```
<AssessmentResult xmlns:shl="http://www.shl.com" xmlns="http://ns.hr-xml.org/2004-08-02" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://ns.hr-xml.org/2004-08-02  AssessmentResult.xsd http://www.shl.com AssessmentResultUserArea.xsd">
<ClientOrderId>
<IdValue name="ThirdPartyCandidateId">XX-00076-000-00007</IdValue>
</ClientOrderId>
<AssessmentStatus><Status>Completed</Status><Details>Successful</Details><StatusDate>2014-04-17</StatusDate></AssessmentStatus>
<UserArea>
<shl:CandidateResult>
<shl:Report />
<shl:Score IsRescored="0">
<shl:Scales>
<shl:Scale Tag="SHL_VAT_GENERAL_ABILITY_SCREEN_SCORE" IsGeneric="1">
    <shl:Name Default="General Ability Screen Score"><shl:Translation ID="en-gb">General Ability Screen Score</shl:Translation></shl:Name>
    <shl:Values>
        <shl:Value Tag="RAW SCORE">0</shl:Value><shl:Value Tag="OTHER">0</shl:Value>
    </shl:Values>
</shl:Scale>
</shl:Scales>
</shl:Score>
<shl:StatusCode>0</shl:StatusCode>
</shl:CandidateResult>
</UserArea></AssessmentResult>
```

Comment: You seem to have a mixture of XmlDocument and LINQ to XML... which do you want to use? Do you *have* to use XPath? This is trivial to do with LINQ to XML's navigation methods. Additionally, please include details of the errors you're getting.

Comment: Hi Jon, I just updated my post. I copied this example from Microsoft site and xPath is seems quick way to read value from xml document. heres the error:  {"Object reference not set to an instance of an object."}

Comment: Additionally, it would make the XML a lot easier to read if you'd indented it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can simplify your code a little bit. This code works

```
XDocument xDoc = XDocument.Load(filename);
XmlNamespaceManager namespaceManager = new XmlNamespaceManager(xDoc.CreateNavigator().NameTable);
namespaceManager.AddNamespace("shl", "http://www.shl.com");

var child1 = xDoc.XPathSelectElement("//shl:Scale[@Tag='SHL_VAT_GENERAL_ABILITY_SCREEN_SCORE']/shl:Values/shl:Value", namespaceManager);
```

Comment: Hi ezi, How should i write this one [  sJTCandidateID = xDoc.XPathSelectElement("//ClientOrderId/IdValue[@name='ThirdPartyCandidateId']", namespaceManager1).Value; ]

Comment: @ejazrehman Just add another (default) namespace `namespaceManager.AddNamespace("defns", "http://ns.hr-xml.org/2004-08-02");` and use `var sJTCandidateID = xDoc.XPathSelectElement("//defns:ClientOrderId/defns:IdValue[@name='ThirdPartyCandidateId']", namespaceManager).Value; `

Comment: Hi EZI, tried the suggested solution but it generating Null Reference exception

Comment: @ejazrehman Can you post the real xml you tested it with? The one in question is invalid...

Comment: Sorry, just updated the xml, should be fine now. The actual xml file is about 112k

Comment: @ejazrehman I tested it again. *sJTCandidateID*'s content is `XX-00076-000-00007`

Comment: Thanks for your help so far, I am still getting same error, I am using VS2010 + .NET4

Answer (score 0):

If your *only* requirement is to get at the `shl:Value` element, then that's really easy with LINQ to XML - I wouldn't personally use XPath to do it:

```
XNamespace shl = "http://www.shl.com";
XDocument doc = XDocument.Load(...);
XElement element = doc.Descendants(shl + "Scale")
                      .Where(x => (string) x.Attribute("Tag") == "...")
                      .Descendants(shl + "Value")
                      .Single();
```

And for the Status and ClientOrderId parts:

```
// Default namespace in the document
XNamespace ns = "http://ns.hr-xml.org/2004-08-02";
XDocument doc = XDocument.Load(...);
XElement orderId = doc.Descendants(ns + "ClientOrderId")
                      .Single(x => (string) x.Attribute("name") == "ThirdPartyCandidateId");
XElement status = doc.Descendants(ns + "AssessmentStatus")
                     .Elements(ns + "Status")
                     .Single();
```

Comment: Hi Jon, There could be 10s of shl:Scale nodes with different @Tag value and each contains shl:value node. I have to select the relevant shl:Scale node to get the value.

Comment: @ejaz: Sorry, missed that - but you can use Where just like in the later examples. Will edit when I get a chance.

Comment: @ejazrehman: I've edited my answer now to show you what I meant.

Comment: Thanks for your help so far, I am getting following error on compile {'System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable<System.Xml.Linq.XElement>' does not contain a definition for 'Element' and no extension method 'Element' accepting a first argument of type 'System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable<System.Xml.Linq.XElement>' could be found}, I am using VS2010 + .NET4 framework, Thanks

Comment: @ejazrehman: Do you mean for what was on the very last line? Fixed now - that's assuming there *is* only one `Status` element.

Comment: @ShafKhan: Please don't make edits just to make non-code elements into code font. Neither "LINQ to XML" nor "XPath" should be in a code font. (Looking at your edit history, you've made many such edit. Please think very carefully before doing so. Things like programming languages are *not* code elements - whereas class names etc are.)